# Passing variables onto a MongoDB Query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

My collections has the following documents

```
{
  cust_id: "0044234",
  Address: "1234 Dunn Hill",
  city: "Pittsburg",
  comments : "4"
},

{
  cust_id: "0097314",
  Address: "5678 Dunn Hill",
  city: "San Diego",
  comments : "99"
},

{
  cust_id: "012345",
  Address: "2929 Dunn Hill",
  city: "Pittsburg",
  comments : "41"
}
```

I want to write a block of code that extracts and stores all cust_id's from the same city. I am able to get the answer by running the below query on MongoDB :

```
db.custData.find({"city" : 'Pittsburg'},{business_id:1}).
```

However, I am unable to do the same using Python. Below is what I have tried :

```
ctgrp=[{"$group":{"_id":"$city","number of cust":{"$sum":1}}}]
myDict={}
for line in collection.aggregate(ctgrp) : #for grouping all the cities in   the dataset
    myDict[line['_id']]=line['number of cust']
for key in myDict:
    k=db.collection.find({"city" : 'key'},{'cust_id:1'})
    print k
client.close()
```

Also, I am unable to figure out how can I store this. The only thing that is coming to my mind is a dictionary with a 'list of values' corresponding to a particular 'key'. However, I could not come up with an implementation about the same.I was looking for an output like this

For Pitssburg, the values would be 0044234 and 012345.

Comment: What is your expected result? use the  [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33729700/edit) link on your question to add it. Also there is pymongo [Tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: I have given the expected output. for the key 'Pittsburg', the values should ' be '0044234' and '012345'. Or , if there is a better way to store instead of this.

Comment: so you want to get a list like this `['0044234', '012345']` if I am correct. Also `cust_id` is distinct right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want this list of 'values' corresponding to the key 'Pittsburg' in a dictionary. Cust_id is distinct, only after grouping it(as I have done in my code). Otherwise, the collection originally contains a number of documents with same cust_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) method which is the best way to do this.

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db.collection
```

then:

```
collection.distinct('cust_id', {'city': 'Pittsburg'})
```

Yields:

```
['0044234', '012345']
```

or do this client side which is not efficient:

```
>>> cust_ids = set()
>>> for element in collection.find({'city': 'Pittsburg'}):
...     cust_ids.add(element['cust_id'])
... 
>>> cust_ids
{'0044234', '012345'}
```

Now if you want all "cust_id" for a given city here it is

```
 >>> list(collection.aggregate([{'$match': {'city': 'Pittsburg'} }, {'$group': {'_id': None, 'cust_ids': {'$push': '$cust_id'}}}]))[0]['cust_ids']
['0044234', '012345']
```

Now if what you want is group your document by city then here and find distinct "cust_id" then here is it:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pipeline = [{'$group': {'_id': '$city', 'cust_ids': {'$addToSet': '$cust_id'}, 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}]
>>> pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
[{'_id': 'San Diego', 'count': 1, 'cust_ids': ['0097314']},
 {'_id': 'Pittsburg', 'count': 2, 'cust_ids': ['012345', '0044234']}]
```

Comment: But I was looking to pass the value dynamically instead of specifying' Pittsburg' explicitly. I have just illustrated an example with the help of Pittsburg. If you have a closer look at the line numbers 5 and 6 of the code, I think you will understand what I am trying to do . Here,'key' will be a different city name every time the loop iterates.
 Also, could you please explain what you meant by 'client side'?

Comment: Thanks a lot . This works. I still had one doubt though- what is the data structure for the variable 'pipeline'? I wanted to know this as I need to perform a similar operation on top of this.So, I have to store these values in order to use them rather than just print them. What I mean is something like this : For each of the cust_ids corresponding to a particular city, I have to find  their luggage_id(s) from another collection.